# Is correct to say $(B_X,\sigma(X,X^*))$ a subtopology for $(B_{X^{**}},\sigma(X^{**},X^*))$

Tags: functional-analysis

> Trying to  prove the following from lecture notes:
>   $X^*$ is separable iff $(B_X,\sigma(X,X^*))$  is metrizable
>
> I come across the argument that uses the question in the title, because we already know  $(B_{X^{**}},\sigma(X^{**},X^*))$ is metrizable and since  $(B_X,\sigma(X,X^*))$ is a topology subspace of $(B_{X^{**}},\sigma(X^{**},X^*))$ (Why?)
>
> Then is easy to see $(B_X,\sigma(X,X^*))$  is metrizable.

I don't understand why would it be a subspace since we aren't talking about same elements from a given set.

Perhaps is an error from the notes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A net $(x_i)$ converges to $x$ in $(B_X,\sigma(X,X^{*}))$ iff $x^{*}(x_i) \to x^{*}(x)$ for all $x^{*} \in X^{*}$ iff $x_i \to x$ in $(B_{X^{**}}, \sigma(X^{**},X^{*}))$. Hence $B_X$ with weak topology is a topological subspace of $B_{X^{**}}$ with its weak* topology.